# Sequelize string is not a function error , why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Please need your help . 
Why i got the strange error for String(150) in nickname object ?

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const devOptions = require('./../config/config').connectionConf.development;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  devOptions.database,
  devOptions.username,
  devOptions.password,
  {
    host: devOptions.host,
    dialect: devOptions.dialect
  }
);

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
      primaryKey:true,
      type:sequelize.BIGINT,
      allowNull:false 
   },
    nickname: {
      type:sequelize.STRING(150),
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    email: {
      type:sequelize.STRING(150),
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    user_password: {
      type:sequelize.STRING(150),
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    created_at: {
      type:sequelize.Date,
      created_time:sequelize.NOW,
      allowNull:false
    },
    updated_at: {
      type:sequelize.Date,
      allowNull:false
    }
  }, {});
```

> > TypeError: sequelize.STRING is not a function
> >         at Object. (E:\Projects\JavaScript\couponsystem\src\models\schema.js:21:22)
> >         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
> >         at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
> >         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
> >         at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
> >         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
> >         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
> >         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> >         at Object. (E:\Projects\JavaScript\couponsystem\src\models\generator.js:1:78)
> >         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
> >         at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
> >         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
> >         at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
> >         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
> >         at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
> >         at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
> >         at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrigued by the fact that you couldn't access the data types with `sequelize`, I started to review the main class of the module.

When you do this `const Sequelize = require('sequelize');` you are calling an interface that extends the data types (they are also an interface), for that reason you can use BIGINT or STRING without any problem.

**But when you do this**

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    devOptions.database,
    devOptions.username,
    devOptions.password,
    {
        host: devOptions.host,
        dialect: devOptions.dialect
    }
);
```

You are referring to a constructor (*Construct signatures*) of the interface mentioned above. This causes that the object that is in `sequelize` is the instance to another class or function and not a direct reference to `Sequelize`, that is why they have different properties.

---

In conclusion this would be the correct way to do the code implementation you request.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const devOptions = require('./../config/config').connectionConf.development;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    devOptions.database,
    devOptions.username,
    devOptions.password,
    {
        host: devOptions.host,
        dialect: devOptions.dialect
    }
);

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    nickname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    user_password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.Date,
        created_time: Sequelize.NOW,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.Date,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {});
```

> Construct signatures in interfaces are not implementable in classes; they're only for defining existing JS APIs that define a 'new'-able
>   function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, for more info, read the docs below.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const devOptions = require('./../config/config').connectionConf.development;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  devOptions.database,
  devOptions.username,
  devOptions.password,
  {
    host: devOptions.host,
    dialect: devOptions.dialect
  }
);

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
      primaryKey:true,
      type:sequelize.BIGINT,
      allowNull:false 
   },
    nickname: {
      type:sequelize.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    email: {
      type:sequelize.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    user_password: {
      type:sequelize.STRING,
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    },
    created_at: {
      type:sequelize.Date,
      created_time:sequelize.NOW,
      allowNull:false
    },
    updated_at: {
      type:sequelize.Date,
      allowNull:false
    }
  }, {});
```

[Docs, Extra info](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html)

Comment: What the problem with such syntax ??? type:sequelize.STRING(150) 
docs - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#data-types

Comment: Well, the error is very specific. STRING is not a function. so either a wrong "Sequalize" is being required. or the documentation is wrong. or the output is lying. OR, more probable. the "sequalize" const is initiated with irrelevant parameters.

Comment: @ArelSapir The doc: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes, clearly states that `sequalize.STRING` is a function.

Comment: So, as i said. It can be one of these cases: either a wrong "Sequalize" is being required. or the documentation is wrong. or the output is lying. or the "sequalize" const is initiated with the wrong parameters.

Comment: Any difference for sequelize.STRING and Sequelize.STRING ?

Comment: I explained the difference in my answer and the solution to your code also @Maks.Burkov